# Groovy formatter/beautifier in Visual Studio Code

Tags: groovy, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

For supported files in VSCode we get an option (when you right click on the file editor) to `Format Document (ALT+SHIFT+F)`.

But unfortunately for Groovy this option is not available. And [according to the VSCode community](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36546), there are no plans to implement this feature.

Is there an alternative solution available, specifically for VSCode?

Answer (score 19):

I don't know how well this works for formatting other than indentation, but I simply changed the file extension from .groovy to .js, right clicked in the file, and selected "Format Document". It fixed the indentation for me.

Comment: isn't `.java` formatter even more suitable for `.groovy`? Will have to try it myself...

Comment: Nice one, but it doesn't indent `sh` inside `steps` properly. More importantly, it can mess up the `sh` code by changing something like `git checkout -b` to `git checkout - b`, notice the unwanted "beauty" space! With that caveat, it's a fine workaround.

Comment: Pretty close to what I wanted, so +1 :)

Answer (score 11):

There is now a Visual Studio Code extension to Lint, Format and Auto-fix Groovy and Jenkinsfiles ! :)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint *Visual Studio Code extension embedding npm-groovy-lint, itself embedding CodeNarc*

[image]

Comment: meh, installed it, I try to run format and nothing happens

Comment: at least if doesn't correct indentation, it changed something it seems

Comment: Please can you post your issue there ? https://github.com/nvuillam/vscode-groovy-lint/issues

Comment: (you can also try to install java on your computer if you don't have it yet)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Doesn't fix indentation

Comment: The formatter was not enabled by default, I had to press `Shift` + `Alt` + `F` and configure it as the default formatter for `.groovy` files. Once I did this, it started formatting on save.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I'm still looking for a solution (or maybe even another IDE)

Comment: npm-groovy-lint currently have maintenance issues, but it will work again someday

Answer (score 5):

It would only be available via an extension, which you can search for [in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/).

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there are many extensions for Groovy at all. And if that can be considered an indication of the language's popularity, it's highly unlikely that broad support would ever be added to VS Code out of the box.

Comment: Incoming... I'm building a vscode extension for npm-groovy-lint, and formatting is in progress 

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy is this built yet?

Comment: @KevinSummersill , https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint , I'll publish a version with "Format" soon ( you can already format by using "Fix errors", but it also fix other errors than format like import order etc .... )

Comment: @KevinSummersill I just released 0.5.1, which contains support of "Format document" VsCode command ! :) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint

Comment: Unable to install 'nicolasvuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint' extension because it is not compatible with the current version of VS Code (version 1.40.1).

Comment: Just upgrade your vscode to the latest version :)

Comment: Did you start writing the answer, then notice there was no plugin?! :D