# VSCode and Jenkinsfiles. How do I format them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to fix formatting in Jenkinsfiles in VSCode 'Shift-Alt F' gives me "There is no formatter for 'groovy' files installed" and pops open an extensions sidebar with no relevant extensions that help do the formatting.

How can I format my files. Thanks. I have 'Jenkinsfile Support' and 'cod-groovy' installed. Still no dice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Groovy There is no option called `Format Document (ALT+SHIFT+F)`. [More details](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36546)

But there is an tricky method to do this,

1. Change your `.groovy` file extension to `.js`.
2. After that **right click** on the file and select `Format Document`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `More details` link is broken. Also, you could've just mark is duplicated rather than just answering the same stuff again.

**Duplicate**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335369/groovy-formatter-beautifier-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @Subham this question is slightly different. Jenkinsfiles have a bit in common with run of the mill Groovy files but they aren't exactly the same.

Comment: This extension worked for me: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ekeel.groovy-beautify

Answer (score 5):

You can use this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivory-lab.jenkinsfile-support called JenkinsFile Support.

And also use the workaround defined here (using the `files.associations` option of VSCode) to give linting for any file with the Jenkinsfile string in the filename https://github.com/sgwozdz/jenkinsfile-support/issues/62#issuecomment-829353453

```
    "files.associations": {
        "[Jj]enkinsfile*": "jenkinsfile"
    }
```

If you don't want to use external extensions, you can use the groovy Id in your settings (just remember, Groovy is not one to one to Jenkinsfiles)

```
    "files.associations": {
        "[Jj]enkinsfile*": "groovy"
    }
```

Comment: This plugin does not appear to have a feature for formatting a Jenkinsfile.

Comment: This does not have a formatter

Answer (score -3):

You can use Vs Code Groovy Lint extension to format your jenkinsfiles :)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint

Comment: why was this voted won, did it not work?

Comment: There was some issues that have been solved... try by yourself and upvote if it works for you :)

Comment: Jenkinsfile formatting does not work